# How to obtain a list of direct descendants (directories and files) of the current directory with their attributes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

There is a directory (denoted by `drctr`). It contains a number of direct descendants (denoted by `drctr_1`, `drctr_2`, `file_1`, `file_2` etc. ). Then `drctr_1` contains a number of its direct descendants (denoted by `drctr_1_1`, `drctr_1_2`, `file_1_1`, `file_1_2` etc. ).

Question: given `drctr`, is it possible to obtain a list of its direct descendants (`drctr_1`, `drctr_2`, `file_1`, `file_2` etc.) with their attributes (that is, not including `drctr_1_1`, `drctr_1_2`, `file_1_1`, `file_1_2` etc.)?

I tried `attrib /d` — it does not work without an additional `/s`, but this will include all files and directories from all subdirectories. But the problem is, if the algorithm will check each subdirectory and file recursively, this will waste a lot of time without any purpose.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  Make up your mind which scripting language you want to do this in.

Comment: @jwdonahue: if it's possible in `cmd`, I want to know how. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer I can think of is:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@rem @set prompt=$G

@rem %CD% would have been the default anyway, but set _root to whatever suits you.
@rem It can even be a parameter such as %1 for instance.
@set _root=%CD%
@for /f %%G in ('dir /b %_root%') do @attrib /D "%%G"
@pause
```

But that will print the entire path/filename along with its attribute, which is the default output for attrib. Let me know if you have additional requirements.

`@for %G in (*) do @attrib "%G"` will also work in the current directory (files only), right from the command line.  But then, so will `attrib *`.

Comment: All I see is a message telling that it is not allowed to use a parameter `/D` without `/S`.

Comment: What version Windows are you running?

Comment: This is for Windows 7

Comment: Try `where attrib` and tell me what it says.

Comment: `C:\Windows\System32\attrib.exe`. Maybe it's better to edit the question and ask for Cygwin solution?

Comment: Open a console window and run the program from there.  Click on Start and type cmd, then select Command Prompt.  I suspect you're not running the real cmd.exe from whatever goofy environment you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164730/discussion-between-jwdonahue-and-lyrically-wicked).

Comment: "I suspect you're not running the real cmd.exe" — it is definitely not the case (I tried it on different non-related PCs).

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164730/discussion-between-jwdonahue-and-lyrically-wicked